# CSV Error when reading from file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file in python, but am getting an error with the second sort operation. I'm completely new to this - any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
import csv

file_var = open('class.csv')
csv_file = csv.reader(file_var)
newlist = []

for row in csv_file:
    row[1] = int(row[1]) #Convert the string values into integers
    row[2] = int(row[2])
    row[3] = int(row[3])
    minimum = min(row[1:3]) #Finds the lowest score for each student
    row.append(minimum) #Adds it to the list
    maximum = max(row[1:3]) #Finds the highest score for each student
    row.append(maximum) #Adds it to the list
    average = round(sum(row[1:3])/3) #Calculate the average of the 3 scores and rounds to nearest whole no.
    row.append(average) #Adding it to a list
    newlist.append(row[0:3]) #adding each row to the newlist - [0:4] the range of items on each row

lowscore = [[x[2], x[0]] for x in newlist] #For sorting lowest scores
print('\nLowest scores\n')
for entry in sorted(lowscore): #iterate through lowscore and sort based on [0]
    print(entry)

highscore = [[x[2], x[0]] for x in newlist]
print('\nHighest scores\n')
for entry in sorted(maximum): #iterate through highscore and sort based on [0]
    print(entry)

avgscore = [[x[2], x[0]] for x in newlist]
print('\nAverage scores\n')
for entry in sorted(average): #iterate through average and sort based on [0]
    print(entry)
```

Comment: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" for line 26 in the code.

Comment: `maximum` is defined here: `maximum = max(row[1:3])`. It's a number, not a list. That's why.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge - how would I correct this?

Comment: You're forgiven :P `lowscore`, `highscore` and `avgscore` all do the same thing. They all refer to `[[x[2], x[0]] for x in newlist]`.

Comment: You could probably do `sorted(newlist, key=lambda x : x[column_you_want_to_sort_by])` so to sort by the minimum (if it's `newlist[4]`), you could do `sorted(newlist, key=lambda x : x[4])` and in a loop: `for entry in sorted(newlist, key=lambda x : x[4]): print entry`. You can add `reverse=True` to `sorted()` to, you guessed it, reverse the sort order: `sorted(newlist, key=lambda x : x[4], reverse=True)`

Comment: OK - I see. Thank you very much for helping me with this :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I hope it works as intended.

Comment: Correction: *"(...) so to sort by the minimum (if it's `newlist[4]`), you could do (...)"* should have been "(...) so to sort by the minimum (if it's `row[4]`), you could do (...)". `newlist` is the list of lists (rows) and `row` is, well, the row. Anyway, it doesn't change the code.